# Javascript debug output

Tags: javascript

I wanted a no-nonsense version of DebugOut in JavaScript. This is what I came up with:

```
function debugOut(ctlstring)
{                   // debugOut
var pieces = ctlstring.split("%");
var s = pieces[0];
for (var iarg = 1; iarg < arguments.length; ++iarg)
    {
    s += arguments[iarg];       
    if (iarg < pieces.length)
        s += pieces[iarg];
    }
console.log(s);
}                   // debugOut
 . . . 
// E.g.:
debugOut("% was % % of the time", "Killroy", "here", 0.42);
```

Can anyone suggest a more economical or elegant way?

Comment: You may want the code review exchange if it's working code. You'd also need to define "elegant" as that is subjective.

Comment: You sure you are [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)? There are stackexchange sites that handle code-reviews - SO generally handles _broken code_

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function debugOut(ctlstring, ...params) {
    for(var arg of params) {
        ctlstring = ctlstring.replace('%', arg);
    }
    console.log(ctlstring);
}
// E.g.:
debugOut("% was % % of the time", "Killroy", "here", 0.42);
```

Answer (score 0):

Cool! So where's the code review section of SO?